# All possible bitonic sets of given digits N

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

We know that a bitonic sequence has a increasing and then decreasing sequence of digits like:

```
{6,7,8,9,5,4,3,2,1}, {5,7,8,9,6,4,3,2,1}  are bitonic sets for N=9
```

Is there any efficient algorithm for finding all possible bitonic sets for given no of digits N.

We can generalize this case for a set of size N.

> There exist some element (K) in the set for which:
>
> N(i) > N(i+1) true for all elements right of k.
>
> N(i+1) > N(i) true for all elements left of k inclusive.

```
like for {6,7,8,9,5,4,3,2,1}, k = 9
```

Now the elements in the sets will be unique.

We have to find all unique sets following above bitonic property?

Kindly correct if i am doing some mistake in using terminology.

Comment: Must they be strictly increasing/decreasing? What are the rules? Or are you simply interested in bitonic sequences $$x_1\leq x_2\leq ...\leq x_k\geq...\geq x_n$$ with some constraints, $x_i\geq 0,\max(x_i)=d$. In your case $d=9$.

Comment: Also, in your examples no digits were repeated. Was that on purpose.

Comment: There are $N-2$ places where $N$ can be. Then there are only two places where $N-1$ can be. Then there are only one or two places where $N-2$ can be. And so on. So it shouldn't be hard to write a program to list all the sequences, for any given $N$.

Comment: Any thoughts, quintin?

Comment: I was thinking like fixing the location of biggest number N then N-1 can only be at most distance of 1 right or left of N, N-2 at most at distance of 2 right or left of N and so on... Then there are (n-2) possible locations where N can be placed but still i am not able to generate permutations for this.

Comment: If you want to be sure I see a comment meant for me, you have to write @Gerry in it. Why not try writing down all the answers for $N=4$ in a systematic way, then try it for $N=5$, see if you can work out the systematic way to generate all the permutations.

Comment: @gerry i came to above conclusion after writing those example permutations .. but i was not able to come up with generic solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an algorithm. Place $N$, then $N-1$, then $N-2$, and so on, down to one, as follows: whenever you have a choice of places to put a number, place it as far left as you can; when you complete a permutation, go back to the last place where you had a choice to make, and make the first choice farther to the right, and proceed as before.

Here's what it generates for $N=5$:

45321, 35421, 25431, 15432, 34521, 24531, 14532, 23541, 13542, 12543, 23451, 13452, 12453, 12354.

Comment: this really helped in finding the solution that i posted. Can't up vote because of my lower points.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the count of all combination of sets in bitonic sequence:
Let N = 6

Fixing 6 at position 2 will produce set like this:

```
_ 6 _ _ _ _
```

So we have to choose 1 digit from rest 5 digits such that sequence is increasing, we can do this in **5C1** ways.

```
_ _ 6 _ _ _
```

Now we have to choose 2 digits from rest 5 digits such that sequence is increasing, we can do this in **5C2** ways.

and so on till we have 6 at N-1 position.

So the total number of possible sets will be:

> 5C1 + 5C2 + 5C3 + 5C4 = 2^5 -2

So the no of bitonic sets for any N distinct integers set

> 2^n - 2

Comment: So all you wanted was the **number** of these configurations, not the actual list of configurations? Why didn't you say so? Why did you write, "Is there any efficient algorithm for **finding** all possible bitonic sets for given no of digits $N$", rather than ask for a way to **count** them? Why did you write, "We have to **find** all unique sets following above bitonic property"?

Comment: @gerry It is relevant if we want just the count. Question stays the same.